# Error to load the process with the projects on Visual Studio Code (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

[image: pic of the problem on Visual Studio Code]

I do not how but when VSC recovered the last use, I denegated and the problem came of.
I do not how to deal with it. Somebody who be a master with the C# lenguaje or .Net environtment please help me because my understood on this technology is so poor.
PD: Sorry for my English, i am from Argentina.

I created a new solucion with the command: dotnet new sln
but the error is persisting.

Comment: Open the csproj file and look which version the project is for (e.g. net8), then check if you have the SDK installed. Solution from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/388

Comment: Per suggestion here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/388#issuecomment-1678341581 you can try installing the latest stable version of .NET 7 - this may help you. I think the C# devkit does require .NET 7.  Download link here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0  That is a confusing page but look for the ASPNet **Hosting Bundle** if you are expecting to do anything web development related, and it won't hurt anyway, and is recommended on Windows :)

Comment: You are getting compiler errors, possible in a child project.  Use menu View : Error List to see compiler errors.

Comment: Ignore vscode for now, it will complicate things. Use the command line to build your projects and solutions. Read any error messages and fix any errors. Then restart vscode and all should be good. Command: `dotnet build "./path to .csproj or .sln"`

Comment: Thank you for the tips and recommendations. I restarted the C# extensions and it is working now. Thank you again.